# Updating Group Number based on swap records in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I just have a two column says like below

```
Ref     Comp
 A       B
 B       A
```

I have the data like this like swapping. Now i just need to provided the same group number for both the records like mentioned below. I our case both the records are same so i need to provide same number for both the records in seperate column. Please provide any solution for this.

```
GROUP      REF       COMP
  1         A         B
  1         B         A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Window Function `dense_rank ...`  in the over(...) use just the order clause: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2c551e355d6753d2f75a544e91fca3de))

```
select dense_rank() over( order by least(ref,comp), greatest(ref,comp) ) as "Group" 
     , ref 
     , comp
 from <your_table>  
order by "Group", least(ref,comp);
```

For demo, I added a couple additional data rows. I seldom trust test result set with only 1 basic item. In this case "Group".